# How to check if array has more than one specific element by one iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to check if array has more than one specific value by one iteration
For example, we have two arrays:

```
   const arr = [{prop: 'test'}, {prop: "test1"}, {prop: "test3"}];
   const arr2 = [{prop: 'test3'}, {prop: "test"}, {prop: "test2"}];
```

I need to get `true` if array object elements have `prop` with value `test` and `test1` when I put it in `if` statement for example.I need to get `true` only if both values exists, If we have not at least one of them I need to get `false` :

```
   const arr = [{prop: 'test'}, {prop: "test1"}, {prop: "test3"}]; //true
   const arr2 = [{prop: 'test3'}, {prop: "test"}, {prop: "test2"}]; //false
```

Comment: The line *'...If we have not at least one of them I need to get `false`'* may be interpreted as if 1 of 2 desired values is found, it is still `true` to be returned, whereas your desired output for `arr2` is `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check a pre-existing whitelist (i.e. `test` and `test1`) against your array. You can conver your array of objects objects into plain array that contains just the `prop` values for easy comparison, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const mappedArray = arr.map(v => v.prop);
```

And then, you can simply check if all elements in your whitelist is found in this mapped array:

```
['test', 'test1'].every(x => mappedArray.includes(x));
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const arr = [{prop: 'test'}, {prop: "test1"}, {prop: "test3"}];
const arr2 = [{prop: 'test3'}, {prop: "test"}, {prop: "test2"}];

function mustContainValues(arr, whitelist) {
  const mappedArr = arr.map(v => v.prop);
  return whitelist.every(x => mappedArr.includes(x));
}

console.log(mustContainValues(arr, ['test', 'test1']));  // true
console.log(mustContainValues(arr2, ['test', 'test1'])); // false
```

Comment: in general, it looks good to me but maybe is it a way to optimize your solution because I have large arrays, and it looks for me a lot of manipulation with an array (map, every, includes) ?

Comment: Performance-wise it shouldn't be too bad: the `Array.prototype.map` is run only once per array that you want to check, and the `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.includes` are computationally the same as doing a for loop and checking if each value has an indexOf > -1 in the mapped array.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a single pass, build a structure that keeps track of the prop values that must be present (must not be missing).  Run through the array and tick them off as they are found.  This runs in O(n) where n is the length of the big array...

```js
// array is a long array of objects
// prop is the prop to check in the long array
// mustHaves is a short array of values that must be present in prop
function check(array, prop, mustHaves) {
  let missing = {}
  for (const key of mustHaves) missing[key] = true
  array.forEach(e => {
    if (missing[e[prop]]) { missing[e[prop]] = false }
  })
  return Object.values(missing).every(v => !v)
}

const arr = [{prop: 'test'}, {prop: "test1"}, {prop: "test3"}];
const arr2 = [{prop: 'test3'}, {prop: "test"}, {prop: "test2"}];

const propToCheck = 'prop'
const mustHaves = ['test', 'test1']

console.log(check(arr, propToCheck, mustHaves))
console.log(check(arr2, propToCheck, mustHaves))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to build an object using reduce:

```
   const func = (arr, value1, value2) =>
    {
      let obj = arr.reduce((acc, rec) => {
    if(rec.prop === value1) acc['hasValue1'] = true
    if(rec.prop === value2) acc['hasValue2'] = true
    return acc
    }, {hasValue1: false, hasValue2: false})
    return obj['hasValue1'] && obj['hasValue2']
    }
```

It will build an object like `{hasValue1: false, hasValue2: false}` and then return boolean AND for found flags. Reduce function will iterate through an array only once
Invoke this function using:

```
console.log(func(arr, 'test', 'test1'))
console.log(func(arr2, 'test', 'test1'))
```